# What kind of crash reason is "info.serviceProcessAssertion is nil"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-log

I've searched everywhere but I couldn't find this parameter (serviceProcessAssertion) anywhere. How can I fix this bug? Why is it happening?      This is my crash log.

```
"2016-05-08 03:33:46","com.xxx.xxxx","2.0.9","date = 2016-05-08 03:33:39 +0000;
buildVersion = 2.0.9;
model = iPad;
systemName = iPhone OS;
systemVersion = 9.3.1;
timeSpent = 469.28;
uid = 3D887DDF-8D43-4D17-8C1B-CDE33552E779;
reason = info.serviceProcessAssertion is nil;
stackTrace = 
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x247d5ba3 ____exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation) + 150
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x23f92dff objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x247d5ad1 -[NSException initWithCoder:] (in CoreFoundation) + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x2956a0df -[_UIViewServiceInterface _initWithConnectionInfo:serviceBundleIdentifier:service:deputyInterfaces:] (in UIKit) + 190
    4   UIKit                               0x2956a56b -[_UIViewServiceInterface _initWithConnectionInfo:service:deputyInterfaces:] (in UIKit) + 46
    5   UIKit                               0x29569f93 __83+[_UIViewServiceInterface connectToViewService:deputyInterfaces:connectionHandler:]_block_invoke (in UIKit) + 78
    6   UIKit                               0x2956860b __112+[_UIViewServiceInterfaceConnectionRequest _connectToViewServiceWithBundleIdentifier:service:connectionHandler:]_block_invoke (in UIKit) + 50
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x24367cbf _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib) + 10
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x24371e7f _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib) + 1762
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x2436ae17 _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib) + 282
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x243736a1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib) + 1572
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x2437307b _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib) + 94
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x24506e0d _pthread_wqthread + 1024
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x245069fc start_wqthread + 8
);",
```